# How to close system dialog from with a service receiver?

Tags: android, service

In my application I have a service that detect onKeyDown press. I want to close system dialog when this key is pressed.

This is the code that I have found to close the system dialogs.

```
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

How can I add this code in my service receiver file, is there a way to override onWindowBackPressed() in BroadcastReceiver class?

Comment: What is "service receiver". This is Service or this is BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: It is a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: So why you don't put the code you found inside the onReceive() callback?

Comment: yes i already tried it, but it gives me an error. How can i add onWindowsBackPressed() method in onReceive()?

Comment: See my answer. What the error you received when you tried this?

Comment: I tried what your answer, the system dialog do not close even after the code you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    context.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
}
```